# Wake On LAN with TL-WR710N in Client mode?

Tags: router, vpn, wireless-router, wake-on-lan

I have a pocket router [TL-WR710N from TP-Link](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TL-WR710N) configured as a WLAN Client for my PC. The WLAN Client logs into the WLAN of my router, while the PC is connected via Ethernet to the TL-WR710N. I can use VPN to get into the local network.

However, sending Magic Packets via the Router or manually via commandline don't seem to do anything. Is there any way to wake up the PC in this WLAN client configuriation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was within the Ethernet card settings of the PC. It had multiple separate options for waking up by a magic packet. One was not enabled. So make always sure you have enabled Wake-On-LAN in BIOS, Network card settings and OS settings and it should work.